# Remove "Edit" and "Delete from files" from SilverStripe UploadField

Tags: php, silverstripe

Via [Silverstripe 3.2](https://www.silverstripe.org/) I am using an [UploadField in a frontend form](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield#using-the-uploadfield-in-a-frontend-form) and it is working fine and looking pretty good:

[image]

However I would like to remove the unneeded "Edit" and "Delete from files" actions from the uploaded file.

Here is the `UploadField` initialisation code I am using:

```php
// upload field
$uploadField = new UploadField('File', 'Upload File');
$uploadField->setCanAttachExisting(false);
$uploadField->setCanPreviewFolder(false);
$uploadField->relationAutoSetting = false;
$uploadField->setAllowedMaxFileNumber(1);
```

Is there a configuration option I'm missing or should I just use CSS to hide the buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I solved a similar issue in the past:

```
// prevent showing preview folder
$uploadField->setConfig('canPreviewFolder', false);
// use a custom button-template with only the wanted buttons      
$uploadField->setTemplateFileButtons('UploadField_FrontendButtons');
```

The template `UploadField_FrontendButtons.ss` could look like this :

```
<button class="ss-uploadfield-item-remove ss-ui-button ui-corner-all" title="<% _t('UploadField.REMOVEINFO', 'Remove this file from here, but do not delete it from the file store') %>" data-icon="plug-disconnect-prohibition">
<% _t('UploadField.REMOVE', 'Remove') %></button>
```

The template above is just a stripped down version of `framework/templates/Includes/UploadField_FileButtons.ss`

Comment: FYI, you can duplicate `framework/templates/Includes/UploadField_FileButtons.ss` to `mysite/templates/UploadField_FileButtons.ss`. The `mysite` version will override the `framework` version.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer Yeah, but that will affect all versions of the UploadField, which is probably not what you want (you'd want them in the Backend, but not in Frontend)